# VHDL data type confusion

Tags: types, vhdl, simulation, vivado

I am trying to simulate the XADC in vivado

I have my testbench code here

```
    library IEEE;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use std.textio.all;

entity test_design_1 is 
end test_design_1;


architecture TB of test_design_1 is

component design_1 is
port (
  dclk_in : in STD_LOGIC;
  eoc_out : out STD_LOGIC;
  vn_in : in STD_LOGIC;
  vp_in : in STD_LOGIC
);
end component design_1;

signal dclk_in : STD_LOGIC;
signal eoc_out : STD_LOGIC;
signal vn_in : STD_LOGIC;
signal vp_in : STD_LOGIC;    
begin
DUT: component design_1 port map (
        dclk_in => dclk_in,
        eoc_out => eoc_out,
        vn_in => vn_in,
        vp_in => vp_in
        );    
process
variable value_SPACE : character;
variable read_col_from_input_buf : line;
variable value_TIME, value_VP, value_VN : integer;
file input_buf : text;

begin 
    file_open(input_buf, "design.txt", read_mode);
          while not endfile(input_buf) loop
            readline(input_buf, read_col_from_input_buf);
            read(read_col_from_input_buf, value_TIME);
            read(read_col_from_input_buf, value_SPACE);           -- read in the space character
            read(read_col_from_input_buf, value_VP);
            read(read_col_from_input_buf, value_SPACE);           -- read in the space character
            read(read_col_from_input_buf, value_VN); 
dclk_in <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(value_TIME, dclk_in'LENGTH));
            vn_in <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(value_VN, vn_in'LENGTH));
            vp_in <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(value_VP, vp_in'LENGTH));
          end loop;
          end process;
end TB;
```

The ports vp_in and vn_in are of type STD_LOGIC but I am getting confused as to convert a number of type decimal (ex: vn_in = 0.0 and vp_in = 0.9) and dclk is range of nanoseconds . [image]

[image]
kindly help me understand how to convert the value in decimal to STD_LOGIC type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Presumably, the vp/vn signals are a differential serial connection from something (maybe LVDS?) You will need to create some behavioural model that converts the analogue values in the text file to the expected digital values.

Comment: How do I do that? do you have examples or can you help me with that? I am new and I am trying my best. Kindly help me.

Comment: You want to convert a decimal type to STD_LOGIC or to STD_LOGIC_VECTOR? STD_LOGIC is a single bit representation, so you can't convert a decimal to STD_LOGIC. So I suppose you mean STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

Comment: Also please provide some more information on your DUT. From my understand in reads 2 inputs (voltage and temperature) and sets an output signal in case of values over some kind of threshold. Also is dclk_in the DUT clock? It looks like you are feeding it an async clock that you read from file.

Comment: No, I have not selected those temp measurements in the ip, I am using a single channel with only the dedicated inputs VP/VN pins Yes the dclk_i is the clk source for the ip.